# BDC service not working

Tags: bdc

So I had to switch SharePoint from one server to another.  Our network guy installed SharePoint onto a new server and I backed up and uploaded my stuff into the new server (with the same name as the original one).  Everything seems to be working alright except for the Business Data Connectivity Service.  I keep getting this error when I click on it:  The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully before retrieving endpoint addresses.    I have tried stopping and starting the service, deleting and re-adding the service, changing the app pools and users it uses, restarting IIS, rebooting the entire server...  I'm at a loss right now and I'm not sure what to do.  Are there any other options or ideas out there that I can try?

EDIT  When I try installing the hotfix, it says that it is not applicable

Comment: The hotfix, I was told, looked to be older and he thought that it would've been included in the update that he had done during the last install.  This is something that I can have him install no matter what, to test it out.  But with the link you provided, I did all the other things and it is still throwing the error.

Comment: So I tried installing the hotfix and it says 'The update is not applicable to your computer.'